# how to use a drop down combo that allows you to select a button that adds it to a collection in visual basic 2008?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add code to a button which will add the selected item from a drop down combo box to another drop down combo box collection.

The code I have tried is:

```
Public Class Form1

Private combobox1 As New Collection()

Private combobox3 As New Collection()

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

combobox1.Add(Me.DropDown)

combobox1.Add(Me.DropDown)

combobox1.Add(Me.DropDown)

combobox1.Add(Me.DropDown)

combobox1.Add(Me.DropDown)

End Sub

Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click

Dim objCombobox1 As ComboBox

        For Each objCombobox1 In combobox1

            If DropDown.SelectedItem = True Then

                combobox3.Add(Me.ComboBox2)

            End If

        Next objCombobox1

        If DropDown.SelectedItem = "" Then

            MessageBox.Show("Information", "No Category was selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Off-topic, but why are you using VB2008? VS2015 Community Edition is fully-featured and available for free.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the program given to us by the University and we have to use that specific one

Comment: Please post more code, including where you're populating the combobox. Also, avoid `VisualBasicCollection`, please use `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` instead.

Comment: Sorry I haven`t been descriptive enough.  What the question is asking me is to use a drop down box that when I select the item I must be able to add it to either a label or somewhere that I can show it then have another method of removing the items that has been added to that collection.

Comment: I think a loop would work for the adding of selected items but I am unsure what I need to do to make the selected items add to the collection in the loop, like I tried:

Comment: Please post your code inside your original question by clicking the Edit link,, not in a comment reply.